# How did researchers calculate the Hazard ratio?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, p-value, hazard, relative-risk

I'm looking at a pdf document and can get the result of the HR. It is actually similiar to calculating the relative risk if I'm right.

How do I get the 1.45 HR or 1.20 HR values based on the 3 rows above (ppis users, h2 users, nonusers). I believe I need more parameters which the researches haven't provided or am I wrong?

**Here is the pic:**

[image]

Comment: You're correct. Unlike relative risk or odds ratio, hazard ratio cannot be computed just by the counts presented in a contingency table. Depends on the software the calculation can differ, but generally we'd need total variance, observed counts, and expected counts, etc. Here the authors only presented observed counts.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Okay, why didn't they present the entire data needed to do such calculation, why are they hiding it, would you perhaps know that?